# XSLT and xsl:for-each with a wildcard

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XSLT-snippet (version 1.0):

```
<p><xsl:value-of select="Items/chkBox1" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="Items/chkBox2" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></p>
<p><xsl:value-of select="Items/chkBox3" disable-output-escaping="yes" /></p>
```

This is working fine. I want to write this smarter using `<xsl:for-each>`, because the number of Items/chkBox may be different, but I cannot make it work. I've tried a number of things like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Items/chkBox*">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" /></p>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But it doesn't work - I get the error:

> Unexpected token '' in the expression. Items/chkBox*<--

How can I use a `<xsl:for-each>` with a wildcard for a number in the end?

Please help!

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There's a good chance you do not need `<xsl:for-each>` but a template match on `chkBox` name. Post more of your xslt even original xml sample for us to show you.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but the answer from @TimC worked beautifully and was just the solution, I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` matches an element. If you want to match on an element name, you have to consider using string functions. In this case, `starts-with`

```
<xsl:for-each select="Items/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'chkBox')]">
```